# Kinematics of a disc

Tags: differential, kinematics

So the kinematics of the contact point of a disc rolling without slip in a Cartesian plane if fairly straightforward. The velocity for the contact point is just 
v = ω r ev
where r is the wheel radius and ev the current direction vector of the wheel.

However, say that you grab the plate and force a rotation around another axis than around where it would roll when rolling freely on the floor. If the plate is vertical, the contact point will not change (if anything due to you drill a hole in the table after while perhaps). However, if you lean the plate, this rotation will clearly induce a change of the contact point. The rate of change is largest when the plate is almost flat to the surface. Does that make sense? I could not find any visualization for this, nor did I bother to formulate this formally as I do not think it helps too much, but if you grab a plate you could probably figure out what I mean.

Where can I find a model for this kinematics? I am modeling a unicycle and no papers I have read so far consider this effect. Probably the answer is related to the projection of the disc onto the plane.

Comment: A couple of comments: If the disk rolls without slipping, the point of contact has $v=0$. $\omega r$ is the velocity of the center of the disk. I did not understand how is your rotation axis is oriented. Is the rotation axis changing direction? Please provide a sketch of how things are supposed to be moving.

Answer (score 1):

hint:

A wheel, tilted wrt  the normal to the plane, will move same as a circular cone having the wheel as (a) base, and axis the wheel axis, so that the cone vertex is at the point where the axis meets the plane ...

Comment: Well that could be a neat trick. I found something here already, let's see if I can find the answer to what I need to know
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138979/instantaneous-axis-of-rotation-and-rolling-cone-motion

Comment: I was thinking that the hint was enough  to conclude that the wheel will rotate along a circle with center at the cone apex, and for the speed you can take the horizontal and vertical components of the angular speed of the wheel ..